# List box resizes when scrolling mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dotnetnuke

Using the mouse wheel keeps expanding the size of the `Listbox` until it reaches the top or bottom of the page.

How can this be functionality be disabled?

Tried setting the `Height` and `MaxHeight` but neither does anything

```
<div style="display:none">
<ListBox id="subject" DataType="String" DataSourceId="test"                                                                                             
   DataField="" DataTextField="cName" DataValueField="ids"
   TargetDataSourceId="" TargetControlId="" ParameterName="" 
   SelectionMode="multiple" SelectedItemsSeparator="," 
   AppendDataBoundItems="true" class="form-control  ids" 
   data-live-search-placeholder="Search for course" 
   data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" 
   title="Select courses of interest" >
</ListBox>
</div>
```

Comment: What is a ListBox, is it third party npm package or some custom component. Need more reference on this.

Comment: why are the attributes of your element outside it as text?

Comment: @madalinivascu it seems typo error I guess

Comment: the code snippet is from a DNN xModPro form.